# Change map from Atlas at the same time it select line of attribute table

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, atlas

I would like to select row of attribute table that correspond the same line of of atlas map.

[image: Atlas layout]

I need that in attribute table, the only line that appear is the same of atlas (identificador is id of table)

[image]

Comment: are you looking for Page queries ? (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/page-queries.htm)

Comment: No. I'm not using arcgis. The implementation is in Qgis.